# How to make a service call to read a config file before angular 2 bootstraps

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular2 application i want to show language specific login page. It is easy to handle when user logins for first time. For example: when user logins for very first time, he gets a list of languages to select from and then login page can be displayed in selected language.We are storing this particular language as a xml tag in configuration file say at location 125.1.0.1/Storage/Configs/MyConfig.config.

Now, The difficulty i am facing when language is set and user logins again. At that time i need to get the language node value from the location and display login page in that language.

I have tried using below code. but ends up with 500 error.

```
public load() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              this._http.get('Myconfig.conf')  
                .map(res => res.text())
                .subscribe(
                  (data:any) => {
                    this.Server = data.server;
                    this.AppKey = data.appkey;
                    resolve(true);
                  },
                  err=>console.log(err)
                );
            });
          }
```

Can some one tell me what i am doing wrong. Is there any work around to achieve this.

Comment: Where are you storing the language settings. Client side or server side ?

Comment: We are storing at serverside

Comment: why cant you store at clientside using localstorage. is it your requirement to store the users preference at server side ?

Comment: Yes we need to store at serverside only. Also we are using a hardware device and on that we are saving these configuration or should say each device will have its own configuration file stored on it.